# How to make the dialog in the HTML page to select a local file path?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am writing a server application that has a web interface for configuration. Some of the options - the paths to local files. Now it's just

```
<input type = "text" ... >
```

but I want a button opening the file selector. I know that there is

```
<input type="file"...>,
```

but it does not allow then to get the path. This is implemented in different ways in different browsers. Sometimes the path is empty, sometimes it is fake. This is due to the security policy in your browser, so that attackers have not seen the structure of user file storage. Is it possible to somehow realize that dialogue with the possibility of obtaining the selected file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm I don't think you could do it, for the rules you already mentioned. The only bug you could use would be:

- Restrict the usage of getting dynamic path only under IE
- Implement ActiveX management from IE
- Communicate with windows' API "GetOpenFileName"

This is really dirty but if you don't mind here is a solution.

rgds